# Is it valid to cast and access to implicit-lifetime types without explicit object creation?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

```
char* t = (char*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 2);
*(float*)t = 1.0f; // or *reinterpret_cast<float*>(t) = 1.0f;
*((float*)t + 1) = 2.0f; // #1
```

In some SO questions, there are answers saying that above code is undefined behaviour because of strict-aliasing violation.

But, I read the paper [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) recently.
I think the paper is saying If you allocate/obtain some storage using certain operations
(such as defining char/byte array, malloc, operator new, ...),
you can treat and use the storage itself as implicit-lifetime types without explicit object creation because the implicit types you want would be created implicitly.

1. If my thought is correct, doesn't the above code now violate strict-aliasing rule?
2. In the above code, Is a float array object created implicitly?
   (If not, #1 is UB because I tried pointer arithmetic on the storage which is not array)

(If you can't understand what i'm saying, tell me plz..  I'm not good at English..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code is legal, and the objects are created implicitly. (since C++20)

I had doubts whether you need `std::launder` or not. Seems not, [`malloc` does it implicitly](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#4) (note "return a pointer to a suitable created object").

Comment: I don't think `std::launder` is required. I think it may be if OP would do something with the intermediate `char*` pointer (e.g. pointer arithmetic on it), but it is only used as unnecessary additional step in casting to `float*` here.

Comment: But, [aligned_storage example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) is using `std::launder` on a region of storage that  `placement new T(...)` was applied to.  

What is the difference from my example?

Comment: @EunhoChoi There's quirky wording in the standard, that says that if you placement-new something into some storage, and then make a pointer to that storage, it "doesn't point to" the newly created object. `std::launder` then makes it "point to" the object, even though the pointer value is unchanged. `malloc`, on the other hand, explicitly says that the pointer points to the implicitly created object, so this quirk doesn't apply.

Comment: Note that even with `aligned_storage`, preserving the return value of placement-new (as opposed to reinterpret_casting pointer to storage itself) also makes launder unnecessary.

Comment: Neither clang or gcc reliably handle all corner cases associated with such code, except when aliasing optimizations are disabled.  In particular, if an assignment would use one type to write a storage which is known to have held the same bit pattern as a different type, both compilers will sometimes behave as though the store re-creates the object of the former type.

Comment: @supercat Can you show an example?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: An example of errant gcc behavior is at https://godbolt.org/z/3rbr83nqs although clang happens to handle that particular example correctly.

Comment: An example of errant clang behavior (which is also erroneous in gcc) is at https://godbolt.org/z/xd3fvrdq3 (this one uses the distinction between 64-bit long and 64-bit long long rather than between structure types with matching layouts).

Comment: How the code is legal? AFAIK, the returned memory may not be aligned to align of float, and hence doesn't this violates strict-aliasing???

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc):  *"[allocates] memory block that is suitably aligned for any scalar type"*.